# What is the standard (?) operator norm usually used in functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am studying introduction to functional analysis, in my lecture notes
I have seen that a norm on functions is used in some proofs.

For example I have seen the following:

> We note that for every (perpendicular) projection $P_{W}$ we have that
>   $||P_{W}||=1$.
>
> Since $$x=P_{W}(x)+P_{W^{\perp}}(x)$$ then
>   $$||x||^{2}=||P_{W}(x)||^{2}+||P_{W^{\perp}}(x)||^{2}$$ hence
>   $||P_{W}(x)||\leq||x||$ and so $||P_{W}||\leq1$.
>
> For $0\neq x\in W$ we have that $P_{W}(x)=x$ hence $||P_{W}||=1$

I believe I can guess that is the intention behind $||P_{W}||$, maybe
it is 
$$
||P_{W}||:=\sup_{x\in V}\{\frac{||P_{W}(x)||}{||x||},\,0\neq x\in V\}
$$

but it was not defined anywhere and I don't like to guess definitions.

Can someone please say what is (probably) the norm used ? is this
the standard norm that I should understand is used when not stated
otherwise ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You have given the correct definition of the operator norm and this is what is intended here. Any time you have a map $T:V \to W$, where you know the norms on the spaces $V$ and $W$, you should assume that $|| T ||$ is the operator norm unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @Tom: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

You have given the correct definition of the operator norm and this is what is intended here.

Any time you have a linear map $T:V\to W$, where you know the norms on the spaces $V$ and $W$, you should assume that $||T||$ is the operator norm unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to tag you and tell you I agreed with Henning that you should post it as an answer so I can accept :)